# Issues with the icon of C# executable set as file handler

Tags: c#, icons, handler, executable

I have created a C# executable that opens a specific file format. I set its icon using the instruction from this page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/339stzf7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The executable file has the assigned icon as expected. However, when I choose this executable as a file handler for a specific file type (e.g. .pdf), the icons of all of those files with that specific format (e.g. .pdf) changes to blank, instead of the icon of my executable file.

When I choose other executable files, for instance, from 7zip or vlc applications, their icons shows up. This does not work with my C# executable. I have also changed the icon of the form in my C# project (winform) as well, but with no luck!

Do you have any though on what may be the problem?

Comment: Why downvote?! How does this have anything to do with my code? I am not doing anything in my code related to icon!!! Just consider it as an empty C# project with a different icon. WHY DOWNVOTE?

Comment: Not that I have to explain my vote, but, the down vote is because your question basically amounts to a url and a complaint that "it doesn't work".  Edit your question to provide enough details to make your question actionable and I would be happy to change my vote.

Comment: @Dan-o there is no code to show. He sets the icon from the designer and the code is automatically generated. The question is genuine.

Comment: Code or not, this question contains *zero* details.

Comment: You may want to describe more details relating to your process in choosing the application file handler for a specific type (or file type association). The link reference refers to loading the icon which you stated works correctly.

Comment: @Dan-o I think the question is clear enough FOR those who are familiar with C# and the basic procedure of changing icon. The thing is that some people do really enjoy downvoting others. If they don't know anything about the question, they don't have to waste stackoverflow space and other's time by just downvoting and not useful comments!

Comment: @JasonAusborn thanks for your comment. I am not using any especial method to change the file handler. I do it just by right clicking on the a file with specific extension (e.g. pdf) -> open with -> choose default program -> more option -> look for another app on this Pc -> then I choose my C# exe file. This is the procedure for windows 8.1. It is pretty much similar for other versions of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue but I have run into this when the icon was home made.  Use an icon editor to verify that the icon you are using has several different image formats for your display options.